# How can I use Glassfish under Linux as a reverse-proxy?

Tags: reverse-proxy, glassfish, sun, opensso

Question says it all. I would like to use SUN Glassfish 2.0x server as a reverse-proxy server, so that when someone hits this server, he/she is transparently redirected to an internal web site, which runs some old Apache (which we cannot upgrade).

We are using Glassfish already under SuSE Linux for multiple applications. This Glassfish would then have SUN Policy Agent (from OpenSSO) installed to control the access to the box.

```
(internet) ---> reverse-proxy ---> internal server
```

Both internal and external should be the same NIC and same IP, preferrably.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason you need to use Glassfish here as reverse proxy. I would suggest you use squid for this. This [article](http://www.visolve.com/squid/whitepapers/reverseproxy.php) mentions how to use squid for this.

Comment: The reason is that Glassfish is the standard web server software at my job. Also, we want to implement SUN Policy Agent to control the access, based on credentials in AD/LDAP. Policy Agent works great with Glassfish.

Comment: The requirement of Policy Agent reduces quite a lot the choice of web software we can use.

Answer (score 1):

Glassfish seems like a strange choice.  I was under the impression that Glassfish is a Java container server.

I'd be more tempted to use [Varnish](http://varnish.projects.linpro.no/) for this, or [Squid](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ReverseProxy).   I don't know much about glassfish, but I suspect it might be a bit similar to Tomcat.   Which probably means you *could* possibly use it as a proxy server, but this wouldn't really be it's *modus operandi*, and is likely to cause problems later on.

Use the right tool for the job.  It's a bit like using the handle of a screwdriver for driving nails, instead of using a hammer.

Comment: Yes, Glassfish is a Java Container, but also a web server, which can serve plain web pages. I just don't know how to use it as reverse-proxy.